# Finitely vanishing vector field on the real projective plane

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, projective-space

I am trying to find a vector field on
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^2 := \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(0,0,0)\} \big/ \sim,
\end{align}
where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation for $z, z'\in \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
\begin{align}
z \sim z' \iff z = \lambda z', \qquad \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\setminus {0}.
\end{align}

Specifically, I am looking for a vector field that vanishes only at finitely many points.

I'm not sure how to start - I can't find any charts that make the answer apparent to me. I'd appreciate if anyone could explain how to go about this problem.

Comment: Hint: If you think of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as $\mathbb S^2/\sim$ with $x\sim -x$, then if you can find a vector fields $X$ on $\mathbb S^2$ with $X(-x) = A_*X(x)$, where $A (x) =-x$, then this vector fields $X$ descend to one on $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. To clarify the notation: is $A_*X(x)$ the pushforward of the vector field X, given the map $A: \mathbb{S}^2/\sim \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2/\sim: x \mapsto -x$? Also, can this be done with a single chart, or will I need 2?

Comment: No, $A :\mathbb S^2 \to \mathbb S^2$. In my argument I did not refer to any chart at all..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying $A$. I was assuming that at some point I would need to use a chart to construct a vector field that was only zero at finitely many points - is this unnecessary?

Comment: A vector fields is a smooth map $X: M \to TM$ so that $X(p) \in T_pM$ for all $p\in M$. You could define $X$ locally on each chart and then show compatibility, but you don't have to do that, right?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you can ensure that $X$ is zero at only finitely many points without explicitly constructing it - would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: You will need to construct such a vector field on $S^2$ first, but it is quite easy (consider some rotations)

Comment: I think I see what you mean now - I think I will give it a try and return if I get stuck Thank you!

Comment: @ArcticChar Everything seems to work out, but there is part I am struggling with: proving $\mathbb{RP}^2 \cong \mathbb{S}^2/\sim$ is a diffeomorphism. The homeomorphism is straightforward enough, but do you have any idea how to show the differentiability?

Comment: Furthermore, do we not want $X(x) = A_*X(x)$ instead?  Because we have $A_*X(x) = X(A(x)) = X(-x)$ by definition?

Comment: To show diffeomorphism, you just need to show that the homeomorphism $f$ you find is smooth and has smooth inverse. This can be checked in any chart I suppose.

Comment: $A_*X(x)$ is by definition a vector in $T_{-x} S^2$, so it can't be $X(x) = A_* X(x)$. It is not true that $A_*X (x) = X(Ax)$ (that's not the definition of the push forward $A_*$).

Comment: To check my definition, if $f$ is a function on $\mathbb{S}^2$, is it defined as $(A_*X(x))(f) = (X(x))(f\circ A)$?

Comment: Yes it is. ${}{}{}{}$